# Multiple subject phrases with present simple

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, noun-phrases

I wrote a sentence which was corrected by my teacher. When I asked them to explain, they weren't very clear.

Here's the sentence I wrote:

```
Busy restaurants and overcrowding on trains increase the risk of infection.
```

My teacher's correction:

```
Busy restaurants and overcrowding on trains increases the risk of infection.
```

My teacher told me that 'increase' needs present simple 's'. I am aware that in normal circumstances a gerund as the subject of the sentence requires the 's', but my sentence has multiple subjects.

To me, the noun phrase and gerund phrase act as 2 separate items and so we should consider the subject of the sentence to be plural. Thus, the 's' is not required.

Are there any rules taking priority here?

Comment: Your teacher is simply mistaken. Some "multi-element noun phrases", such as *Fish and chips is my favourite* can be treated as syntactically singular (more so in British than American English). But this only works in contexts where the multiple elements can naturally be thought of as a "single *collective* thing" (in my example, ***a** meal*). Since that doesn't apply to ***busy restaurants*** and ***overcrowding on trains***, the verb form ***must*** reflect the fact that there are "multiple" subjects.

Comment: FumbleFingers is right. Perhaps if you were to edit this to read "***Both*** busy restaurants and overcrowding on trains..." it might make it more clear to the teacher that you are considering **busy restaurants** and **overcrowding on trains** as multiple subjects.

Answer (score 1):

In a larger context, 'increases' might make sense, but in almost all situations I'm with you in supporting 'increase', as those are two independent things.